# spring validator with around aspect java with additional argument

Tags: java, spring, validation, aop

How to utilize specific argument in spring validator and I cannot merge arguments into a single object?

Say I have a controller like,

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "url",
          consumes = { "application/json" }, produces = { "application/json" },
          method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public MyResponse getMyData(
          @Valid @RequestBody MyRequest myRequest, Errors errors, CustomObject obj){
         return new MyResponse();
}
```

I have a aspect implementation for updating the **CustomObject**

```
 @Around("@annotation(MyAnnotation) && execution(* MyController.getMyData(..))")
        public Object requestsAroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint){
            Object value = null;
            CustomObject obj = new CustomObject();
            try {
                Object[] args = proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs();
                //populate CustomObject
                obj = (CustomObject)args[2];
                obj.setField("value");
                value = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed(args);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return value;
        }
```

CustomObject's updated value I'm able to get in the controller. Now i need to validate **MyRequest** also using a spring custom validator like,

```
@InitBinder
  protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addValidators(new MyCustomValidator());
  }
```

And MyCustomValidator's 'validate()' function is as,

```
@Override
  public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
   validate((MyRequest)target);
}
```

Both aspect and validation are working separately but when both are integrated the validation is failing because target in validate method considers '**CustomObject**' for validation rather than using '**MyRequest**'. Validate method will accept only two arguments while 'getMyData()' method in controller has three. How to resolve this or is there any other approach to achieve a similar solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to assign the name of the object to validate to the *initBinder* (use the name of the object instance, not the class).

```
InitBinder("myRequest")
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
...
```

If it's not working, you can try to give an order to the *aspect* using the **Order** annotation on it or implement the **Order** interface.

Anyway, I'm not totally confident about the correctness of the first two options because I cannot test the code (I answer from a tablet). So, I suggest also a third option, where you put the validation inside the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "url",
      consumes = { "application/json" }, 
      produces = {"application/json" },
      method = RequestMethod.POST)
public MyResponse getMyData(
      @RequestBody MyRequest myRequest, BindingResult result, CustomObject obj){
    MyCustomValidator validator = MyCustomValidator();
    validator.validate(myRequest, result);

    if (result.hasErrors()){
      // do something
    }

    return new MyResponse();
}
```